# Combine elements within list of lists python

Tags: python, list-manipulation

I have a list of the form

```
in_list = [[10, 15], [16,21], [22,25], [26,30], [35,40], [45,50],[51,55]]
```

And I need to combine consecutive lists that contain consecutive integers in the last and first position into lists. So

```
if in[1][0] = in[0][1] + 1:
    out[0] = [in[0][0],in[1][1]]
```

The output will be of the form of

```
out_list = [[10,30], [35, 40], [45,55]]
```

Right now, the code I have does multiple iterations on the *out* list and combines the elements, continuing till the number of elements in the list stops changing after an iteration. How can I achieve this in a more pythonic way?

Comment: I see no `12` in your input. Where does it come from?

Comment: You want a **more pythonic way**. `more` implies `more **than**` : so I suggest you post your entire code so that we can help. Note that such questions should be posted on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Only if the code actually gets included in the question, @IMCoins. As it stands, this question would be off-topic on CR. See also: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Please explain the downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
out = [inp[0]]
for l in inp[1:]:
    if l[0] == out[-1][1] + 1:
        out[-1][1] = l[1]
    else:
        out.append(l)
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote. This code works and is efficient.

Comment: This just overwrites the last element of a list when it detects consecutive lists. It doesn't actually combine them as required.

Comment: It does what the OP asks. Run it

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean one-line stuff using numpy? :)

Try the following shortcut:

```
import numpy as np

# data is of shape (n,2), n=6
data = np.array([[10, 15], [16,21], [22,25], [26,30], [35,40], [45,50],[51,55]]) 

# seek for consecutive numbers
marks = (data[:-1,1]+ 1) == data[1:,0] 

# re-arrange and return to python lists
output = np.stack([data[:-1,0][marks],data[1:,1][marks]],axis=1).tolist()
```

**EDIT**:
Another option using lists:

```
data = [[10, 15], [16,21], [22,25], [26,30], [35,40], [45,50],[51,55]]

mylist = []

def func(x1,x2):
    if x1[1] +1 == x2[0]:
        mylist.append((x1[0],x2[1]))

list(map(func,data[:-1],data[1:]))
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
[(10, 21), (16, 25), (22, 30), (45, 55)]
```

Comment: I have marked the other answer as correct, but your list solution works too. Thank you.